# How to skip a date if it is generated in a loop?

Tags: php, date, datetime

**What this code does:**
It generates dates based on a single day that is grabbed before (`$date`).
It counts always up one week. E.g. If your start date (`$date`) is `07.04.2019` it will generate the dates for `$final_amount` times.

So, if the start of the date is `07.04.2019` and `$final_amount` is: `5` it will output:

```
07.04.2019` (handled in separate code, as the first day is excluded in code!)
14.04.2019
21.04.2019
28.04.2019
05.04.2019
```

**The issue with my code:**
 I need to skip the date if it falls into a holiday. So if e.g. `21.04.2019` is a holiday, it should be skipped and replaced with a new date one week later. It should always have the amount `$final_amount` even if one ore more dates are laying on a holiday.
I have no Idea how this could be accomplished, as I am relatively new to PHP.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE"); //only necessary if the locale isn't already set
$date = new DateTime(helper('com://site/ohanah.date.format', array(
   'date' => $event->start,
   'format' => 'Y-m-d H:i',
   'timezone' => 'UTC'
)));

$date_scn = new DateTime(helper('com://site/ohanah.date.format', array(
   'date' => $event->end,
   'format' => 'H:i',
   'timezone' => 'UTC'
)));

$cnt = 2; // start the termin to count at two as the first one is already defined above
$raw_ticket_type = $event->ticket_types->name;
$filter_numbers = array_filter(preg_split('/\D/', $raw_ticket_type));
$filtered_numbers = reset($filter_numbers);
$first_occurence = substr($filtered_numbers[0], 0, 1);
$final_amount = $first_occurence - 1; // subtract 1 from $first_occurence as it is always one more

for ($i = 0; $i < $final_amount; $i++)
{ // loop
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1W')); //add one week
    $formatted_time = utf8_encode(strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y, %H:%M", $date->getTimestamp()));
    $formatted_time_scnpart = utf8_encode(strftime("%H:%M", $date_scn->getTimestamp()));

    // This is the modal

    echo '<div class="termin-layout"><span class="termin-number-text">' . $cnt++ . '. ' . 'Termin' . '</span>
<span class="termin-date">' . $formatted_time . ' - ' . $formatted_time_scnpart . '</span></div>';
}

echo '</div></div></div>';
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly Your duplicate answers the title, but not the actual question. He doesn't want to exit the loop, he wants to skip that iteration.

Comment: @Barmar Woops, my mistake

Comment: Please do not use `utf8_encode`. It is for the most part a very useless function. There are definitely better ways of doing what you want to do.

Comment: What is the use of goes to operator in `$date-- > add(new DateInterval('P1W'));` Is this a typo?

Comment: @Dharman yes, thanks for pointing this out. I fixed it with an edit. It looks like I copy and pasted this wrong time ago. This was not in the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop instead of the `for` loop. Then you can skip incrementing the counter if a condition is met.

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < $final_amount) {
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1W'));
    if (is_holiday($date)) {
        continue;
    }
    $i++;
    $formatted_time = utf8_encode(strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y, %H:%M", $date->getTimestamp()));
    $formatted_time_scnpart = utf8_encode(strftime("%H:%M", $date_scn->getTimestamp()));

    // This is the modal

    echo '<div class="termin-layout"><span class="termin-number-text">' . $cnt++ . '. ' . 'Termin' . '</span>
<span class="termin-date">' . $formatted_time . ' - ' . $formatted_time_scnpart . '</span></div>';
}
```